# git branch --copyとcheckoutの違いはありますか？

Tags: git

現在のブランチがb1として、下記コマンド2つに違いはありますか？

```sh
git branch --copy b1 b2
git checkout -b b2
```

前者はどこのブランチからでも行える、後者は移動を伴うというのはわかるのですが、上記b2は同じものだと考えて間違いないでしょうか？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`b1` が**非**[追跡ブランチ(tracking branch)](https://git-scm.com/book/ja/v2/Git-%E3%81%AE%E3%83%96%E3%83%A9%E3%83%B3%E3%83%81%E6%A9%9F%E8%83%BD-%E3%83%AA%E3%83%A2%E3%83%BC%E3%83%88%E3%83%96%E3%83%A9%E3%83%B3%E3%83%81#r_tracking_branches)の名前だとすると、質問文中に書かれている理解でも概ね問題ないかと思います。
ですが、一般的な話で言うと違います。

細かいものも含めて誤解を指摘すると:

- `git checkout -b ...` を意味的に分解すると、 `HEAD` の操作(`git checkout`) のついでにローカルブランチ作成する(`-b`)、ということなので、*"移動"* は付随的なものでなく主目的です。
- `git checkout -b b2 b1` と指定することもできるので、`git checkout` も *"どこのブランチからでも行え"* ると言えるでしょう。
- `-b` オプションに相当するのは `git branch b2 b1` です。(`--copy` オプションはつかない; コピーでなく新規作成)

  - `--copy` はブランチの設定もコピーされます。[ユースケース](https://github.com/git/git/commit/52d59cc6452ed1aeec91f4c168a853ea8d9d5496):

    > This is useful for e.g. copying a topic branch to a new version,
    > e.g. work to work-2 after submitting the work topic to the list, while
    > **preserving all the tracking info and other configuration that goes
    >
    > with the branch**, and unlike --move keeping the other already-submitted
    > branch around for reference.

要は、

```
git branch b2 b1
git checkout b2
```

を1つのコマンドにまとめたのが

```
git checkout -b b2 b1
```

です。

ちなみに、

```
git switch -c b2 b1
```

も同じ動作です。

参考:

- [`git-checkout`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout)
- [`git-branch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch)
- [`git-config`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-branchltnamegtmerge)(`branch.<name>.merge` など)

Comment: ありがとうございます！
pull = fetch + mergeみたいなものですね。勉強になります！

Answer (score 1):

ちょっとやってみました。同じものです。
絶対にそうだと確認して、何らかのプログラムに使いたい場合はだめですけど
ちょっと知りたい程度ならやってみて確認でよいのでは。

前者が欲しければ、一次情報あたるしかないですしね。。

以下の確認結果では、★1と★2の値が同じで、copyもbranchも同じコミットをポイントしています。

```
<workdir>>git commit -m "2st"
[master 076b1b6] 2st
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)

<workdir>>git checkout -b branch
Switched to a new branch 'branch'

<workdir>>git log
commit 076b1b61511a85612e7b4f7e29c849ea5657a7f6 (HEAD -> branch, master)
★1

Author: Some User <xxxxx@yyyyy>
Date:   Mon Nov 15 07:15:10 2021 +0900
    2st

...

<workdir>>git checkout master
Switched to branch 'master'

<workdir>>git branch --copy branch copy

<workdir>>git checkout copy
Switched to branch 'copy'

<workdir>>git log
commit 076b1b61511a85612e7b4f7e29c849ea5657a7f6 (HEAD -> copy, master, branch)
★2
Author: Some User <xxxxx@yyyyy>
Date:   Mon Nov 15 07:15:10 2021 +0900

    2st

....
```

Comment: ハッシュが同じだから単純に同じものだと考えていいのか勘ぐってしまいました。
ありがとうございました！